# Is there anyway to optimize `SHOW DATABASES` query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The following is logged multiple times in MYSQL_SLOW_QUERIES:

`Mon Nov 25 07:18:57 2013

 Query_time: 1.467255  Lock_time: 0.000132 Rows_sent: 9  Rows_examined: 9

SET timestamp=1385389137;

SHOW DATABASES`

I am guessing that query was run when I was using the `phpMyAdmin`. Is it an issue with the server or there is something I need to do to fix it?

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/06/25/does-slow-query-log-logs-all-slow-queries/ - is this any use?

Comment: Actually, I am not calling that query. It was phpMyadmin. It is being logged as one of the slow queries. Also, because of this, the server guys are logging labelling my account under CPU Throttle.

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW DATABASES` an sich should not be slow. It can be a bit slower the first time you run the command, when it needs to read the info. It can be slower after a long time, when the info has left the cache.

There are a number of known bugs in MySQL which can cause this, though. Updating your system to the latest stable build will fix this. What version are you currently using?

Comment: I am on bluehost shared hosting. The current MYSQL version is 5.5.34-log

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin 4.1.0-rc1 (available now) hopefully no longer uses SHOW DATABASES; please give it a try.